# Cannot create and save new instance of a model using rails + undefined method `projects' for nil:NilClass - Stack Overflow

Tags: ruby-on-rails, model

I was having trouble getting a new instance of a model to save and someone said it might be my associations so I went back and edited them and also dropped my migrations and reran rake db:migrate (this was probably a mistake but here I am filled with regret and its done) and now I keep getting  `` undefined method `projects' for nil:NilClass - Stack Overflow ``
so now I am quite sure I didn't fix the issue saving and created an entirely new mess as well.

I'll try to include as much detail as I can here. It is probably something much simpler than I realize but I am on the second vaccine dose and feel like trash.

My models

```
class Project < ApplicationRecord
  belongs_to :volunteer
  belongs_to :team

  def self.find_latest_five
    order(id: :desc).limit(5)
  end
end
```

```
class Team < ApplicationRecord
    has_many :volunteers, through: :projects
    has_many :projects

    #validates :content, presence: true 
end
```

```
class Volunteer < ApplicationRecord
has_many :projects
has_many :teams, through: :projects
has_secure_password
end
```

my controllers

```
    helper_method :current_volunteer, :logged_in?
    #these gives access to methods in views
    
    private 
    def current_volunteer
        @current_volunteer ||= Volunteer.find_by_id(session[:volunteer_id]) if session[:volunteer_id]
    end

    def logged_in?
        !!session[:volunteer_id]
    end

    def redirect_if_not_logged_in?
        redirect_to '/' if !logged_in?
    end
end
```

```
class VolunteersController < ApplicationController
    def new
        @volunteer = Volunteer.new
    end



    def create
       @volunteer = Volunteer.new(volunteer_params)
       if @volunteer.save
        session[:volunteer_id] = @volunteer.id
        redirect_to @volunteer
       else
        render :new
       end
    end 

    def show
        redirect_if_not_logged_in?
        @volunteer = Volunteer.find_by_id(params[:id])
        redirect_to '/' if !@volunteer
    end

    private 

    def volunteer_params
        params.require(:volunteer).permit(:username, :email, :password)
    end 

end
```

```
class ProjectsController < ApplicationController
    before_action :redirect_if_not_logged_in?

    def new 
        @project = Project.new
    end

    def create
        #render plain: params[:project].inspect
        #@project = current_volunteer.projects.new(project_params)
        @project = current_volunteer.projects.build(project_params)
        if @project.save!
            flash[:notice] = "Project was succesfully created"
            redirect_to projects_path
        else 
            render :new
    end  
end

    def show
        @project = Project.find(params[:id])
    end


    def index 
        @projects = Project.all 
    end 

    #def index 
       #if params[:volunteer_id] && @volunteer = Volunteer.find_by_id(params[:project_id])
                #@projects = @volunteer.projects
        #else
            #@error = "This isn't an existing volunteer" if params[:volunteer_id]
            #@projects = Projects.all
        #end
    #end


    private 

    def project_params
        params.require(:project).permit(:title, :content)
    end

end
```

```
class TeamsController < ApplicationController
    before_action :redirect_if_not_logged_in

    def index 
        if params[project_id] && @project = Project.find_by_id(params[:project_id])
                @teams = @project.teams
        else
            @error = "That isn't a current project."
            @teams = Team.all
        end
    end


    def new 

        if params[project_id] && @project = Project.find_by_id(params[:project_id])
            @team = @project.teams.build
            @team.save!
        else

            @error = "That isn't a current project." if params[:project_id]
            @team = Team.new

    end 
end

    def create
        @team = current_volunteer.teams.build(teams_params)
        if @team.save 
         redirect_to teams_path 
        else
            render :new
        end
    end

    def show 
        @team = Team.find_by(id: params[:id])
    end

    def edit
        @team = Team.find_by(id: params[:id])
    end

    def update
        @team = Team.find_by(id: params[:id])
        if @team.update(team_params)
            redirect_to team_path(@team)
        else
            render :edit
        end 
    end

    private 

    def teams_params
        params.require(:team).permit(:content,:project_id)
    end
end
```

and the migration tables

```
class CreateProjects < ActiveRecord::Migration[6.1]
  def change
    create_table :projects do |t|
      t.string :title
      t.text :content
      t.belongs_to :volunteer, foreign_key: true
   


      t.timestamps
    end
  end
end
```

```
  def change
    create_table :volunteers do |t|
      t.string :username
      t.string :email
      t.string :password_digest

      t.timestamps
    end
  end
end
```

```
class CreateTeams < ActiveRecord::Migration[6.1]
  def change
    create_table :teams do |t|
      t.string :content
      t.references :volunteer, foreign_key: true
      t.references :project, foreign_key: true

      t.timestamps
    end
  end
end
```

Thank you in advance for any insight you can offer!

Comment: `current_volunteer`, what you are calling `.projects` on, is nil. Where and how is `current_volunteer` set?

Comment: in the applications controller ' class ApplicationController < ActionController::Base

    helper_method :current_volunteer, :logged_in?
    #these gives access to methods in views
    
    private 
    def current_volunteer
        @current_volunteer ||= Volunteer.find_by_id(session[:volunteer_id]) if session[:volunteer_id]
    end

    def logged_in?
        !!session[:volunteer_id]
    end

    def redirect_if_not_logged_in?
        redirect_to '/' if !logged_in?
    end
end
'

Comment: Please add this to your original question

Comment: I'm not sure why this isnt appearing as code in the commentsts so I will add the application controller to my post

Comment: I'd drop all the database tables, delete the schema and run the migrations again. Before doing this keep a backup.

Comment: alas the same issue persists

Comment: @MarkMerritt I faced a similar issue a few months back that messed up my db and schema and I solved it by doing what I proposed. I pointed out that they should take a backup before going this route.

Answer (score 0):

make db:rollback and change *t.belongs_to :volunteer, foreign_key: true* to *t.references :volunteer, foreign_key: true* at projects migration, should help as for me

Comment: this lead me on the correct path to the (other) errors I need to see to get things moving! Thank you!